# FSL - Can I set the path within an fsf file (program setup file) to current working directory?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am performing MRI analysis, and have written a script that loops through all scans for each subject, with the next step being to run a command called feat, which can be seen towards the end of the coding block below.

```
#! /bin/sh
path=~/rj82/james_folder/data_copy/
cd $path

# Loop through the MND and Control directories
for directory in * ; do
cd $path
cd $directory

# Loop through each subject in each directory
for subject in ??? ; do
cd $path/$directory/$subject

# Loop through each scan for each subject
for scan in MR?? ; do
cd $path/$directory/$subject/$scan

# Run feat on each scan
feat design.fsf

cd ..

done
done
done
```

You will also see feat takes a `design.fsf` file which sets the parameters for feat. To make this file I used one MRI scan as input data.

Below I have attached the regions within the `design.fsf` code that show the path of the files used to create the file.

```
# 4D AVW data or FEAT directory (1)
set feat_files(1) "/projects/rj82/james_folder/data_copy/mnd/002/MR02/fmri/fmri_data"

# Add confound EVs text file
set fmri(confoundevs) 0

# Session's alternate reference image for analysis 1
set alt_ex_func(1) "/projects/rj82/james_folder/data_copy/mnd/002/MR02/fmri_ref/fmri_ref_brain"

# B0 unwarp input image for analysis 1
set unwarp_files(1) "/projects/rj82/james_folder/data_copy/mnd/002/MR02/fmaps/fmap_rads"

# B0 unwarp mag input image for analysis 1
set unwarp_files_mag(1) "/projects/rj82/james_folder/data_copy/mnd/002/MR02/fmaps/mag_e1_brain"

# Subject's structural image for analysis 1
set highres_files(1) "/projects/rj82/james_folder/data_copy/mnd/002/MR02/t1/t1_brain"
```

If I run the script (first coding block) feat will run correctly, however as the path within the `design.fsf` file only refers to one scan, it will just continuously run feat on this single scan.

As the subdirectories and files within each subject have the same name, I want to replace the path `"/projects/rj82/james_folder/data_copy/mnd/002/MR02` with the current directory from the script (first coding block), whilst keeping the end portion (e.g `fmri/fmri_data"`) allowing me to loop through and run feat on each subject.

I have tried setting `path=pwd` and replacing the above path with `"$path/fmri/fmri_data"` which does not work, as well as removing the `"/projects/rj82/james_folder/data_copy/mnd/002/MR02` portion entirely, as I hoped it would just use the current directory, but this also doesn't work. Error message is the same for both:

```
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/fmri’: Permission denied
    while executing
"fsl:exec "/bin/mkdir -p $FD" -n"
    (procedure "firstLevelMaster" line 22)
    invoked from within
"firstLevelMaster $session"
    invoked from within
"if { $done_something == 0 } {

    if { ! $fmri(inmelodic) } {
       if { $fmri(level) == 1 } {
              for { set session 1 } { $session <= $fmri(mult..."
    (file "/usr/local/fsl/6.0.4/fsl/bin/feat" line 390)
```

Comment: There is a copy of `design.fsf` in each scan directory?

Comment: @Armali Thanks for the reply!

When I asked the question, there wasn't, but I have now put a copy of ```design.fsf``` in each scan directory. In the parts that require a path I put just the subdirectory names that contain the files and are the same in all scans.

Comment: Could you show one sample line `set feat_files(1) …` as it looks now?

Comment: So for it to run I need something like 

```set feat_files(1) "~/rj82/james_folder/data_copy/mnd/002/MR02/fmri/fmri_data"```

My script navigates into each individual subject and scan, so I have change the design file to:

```set feat_files(1) "/fmri/fmri_data"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get what I was trying to achieve to work, so instead I looped through the same as above, copied my `design.fsf` file into each directory, and edited them with `sed` to have the right path.

```
#! /bin/sh
path=~/rj82/james_folder/data_copy/
cd $path

# Loop through the MND and Control directories
for directory in * ; do
cd $path
cd $directory

# Loop through each subject in each directory
for subject in ??? ; do
cd $path/$directory/$subject

# Loop through each scan for each subject
for scan in MR?? ; do
cd $path/$directory/$subject/$scan

# Copy template design.fsf into each scan folder
cp $path/../design.fsf design.fsf

# Change design.fsf file and replace the directory used 
# to create the template with the current directory
current=$directory/$subject/$scan
sed -i "s|mnd/002/MR02|$current|g" design.fsf

# Run feat using custome design.fsf file
feat design.fsf

cd ..

done
done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

> My script navigates into each individual subject and scan, so I have change the design file to: `set feat_files(1) "/fmri/fmri_data"`

That was a good idea, but in order to make relative paths you have to also remove the leading `/`; thereto also hints the error message `cannot create directory ‘/fmri’`.

With truly relative paths in the `.fsf` file, it should also be possible to use a common `design.fsf` by calling `feat /path/design.fsf`

Comment: I changed that, and it got past the last error I had, but now getting this:

```child process exited abnormally
    while executing
"fsl:exec "${FSLDIR}/bin/feat ${fsfroot}.fsf -D $FD -I $session -init" -b 10 -N feat0_init -l logs "
    (procedure "firstLevelMaster" line 145)
    invoked from within
"firstLevelMaster $session"
    invoked from within
"if { $done_something == 0 } {

    if { ! $fmri(inmelodic) } {
       if { $fmri(level) == 1 } {
              for { set session 1 } { $session <= $fmri(mult..."
    (file "/usr/local/fsl/6.0.4/fsl/bin/feat" line 390)
```

Comment: In the report log it showed:
```FATAL ERROR ENCOUNTERED:
COMMAND:
/usr/local/fsl/6.0.4/fsl//bin/fsl_sub -T 10 -l logs -N feat0_init   /usr/local/fsl/6.0.4/fsl//bin/feat /projects/rj82/james_folder/data_copy/controls/C01/MR01/fmri/fmri_data.feat/design.fsf -D /projects/rj82/james_folder/data_copy/controls/C01/MR01/fmri/fmri_data.feat -I 1 -init
ERROR MESSAGE:
child process exited abnormally
END OF ERROR MESSAGE```

Comment: I'm thinking I might just try making individual design files and do it that way unless you have any other ideas?

Comment: The error message is somewhat hard to read, and I can't see a concrete error reason, but the `design.fsf` path looks strange - did you change the `feat design.fsf` command line, and if yes, how?

Comment: Thanks for your help Armali, I had not changed the feat command line. Not sure why it wasn't working, but I managed to make it work by looping through and editing the design.fsf file for each scan